# How do you pause, stop and reset an AUFilePlayer?

Tags: ios5, audio, core-audio

I am working with core audio using an AUFilePlayer to load a few mp3s into a mixer unit, everything plays great however I am unable to pause the music or rewind the music back to the start. I tried Starting and stopping the AudioGraph, but once the playback is stopped, I can't get it to restart. I also tried using AudioUnitSetProperty to set the file playback to 0

i.e something along these lines:

```
        ScheduledAudioFileRegion rgn;
        memset (&rgn.mTimeStamp, 0, sizeof(rgn.mTimeStamp));
        rgn.mTimeStamp.mFlags = kAudioTimeStampSampleTimeValid;
        rgn.mTimeStamp.mSampleTime = 0;
        rgn.mCompletionProc = NULL;
        rgn.mCompletionProcUserData = NULL;
        rgn.mAudioFile = inputFile;
        rgn.mLoopCount = 1;
        rgn.mStartFrame = 0;

        rgn.mFramesToPlay = nPackets * inputFormat.mFramesPerPacket;

        AudioUnitSetProperty(fileUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_ScheduledFileRegion, 
                             kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0,&rgn, sizeof(rgn));
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: i also tried AudioUnitReset, but that did not seam to work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. In case any of you  ever run into the same problem, here was my solution:

1. On startup, I initialize the AUGraph with an array of file player audio units. I set the play head of each track in the file player audio unit array to zero.
2. On “pause” , first I stop the AuGraph. Then I loop through the array of file player audio units and capture the current playhead position. Each time the pause button is pressed, I  make sure I add the new current playhead position to the old playhead position to get its true position.
3. When the user hits play, I re initialize the AuGraph just as if I was starting the app for the very first time, only I set the playhead to the number I stored when the user hit “pause” instead of telling it to play at the start of the file.
4. If the user clicks stop, I set the stored playhead position to zero and then stop the AuGraph.

Comment: Point 2 is very important. It was what I was missing which lead me to this question.  Also don't use a repitive instrumental song when testing, hard to tell if your pause is actually working!

Answer (score 6):

In case anyone else is dealing with a similar issue, which cost me several hours searching on google, here's what I've discovered on how to *specifically* retrieve and set the playhead.

To get the playhead from an AUFilePlayer unit:

```
AudioTimeStamp timestamp;
UInt32 size = sizeof(timestamp);
err = AudioUnitGetProperty(unit, kAudioUnitProperty_CurrentPlayTime, kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0, &timestamp, &size);
```

The `timestamp.mSampleTime` is the current playhead for that file. Cast `mSampleTime` to a float or a double and divide by the file's sample rate to convert to seconds.

For restarting the AUFilePlayer's playhead, I had a more complex scenario where multiple AUFilePlayers pass through a mixer and can be scheduled at different times, multiple times, and with varying loop counts.  This is a real-world scenario, and getting them all to restart at the correct time took a little bit of code.

There are four scenarios for each AUFilePlayer and it's schedule:

1. The playhead is at the beginning, so can be scheduled normally.
2. The playhead is past the item's duration, and doesn't need to be scheduled at all.
3. The playhead is before the item has started, so the start time can be moved up.
4. The playhead is in the middle of playing an item, so the region playing within the file needs to be adjusted, and remaining loops need to be scheduled separately (so they play in full).

Here is some code which demonstrates this (some external structures are from my own code and not Core Audio, but the mechanism should be clear):

```
// Add each region
for(int iItem = 0; iItem < schedule.items.count; iItem++) {
    AEFileScheduleItem *scheduleItem = [schedule.items objectAtIndex:iItem];

    // Setup the region
    ScheduledAudioFileRegion region;
    [file setRegion:&region schedule:scheduleItem];

    // Compute where we are at in it
    float playheadTime = schedule.playhead / file.sampleRate;
    float endOfItem = scheduleItem.startTime + (file.duration*(1+scheduleItem.loopCount));

    // There are four scenarios:

    // 1. The playhead is -1
    //    In this case, we're all done
    if(schedule.playhead == -1) {
    }

    // 2. The playhead is past the item start time and duration*loopCount
    //    In this case, just ignore it and move on
    else if(playheadTime > endOfItem) {
        continue;
    }

    // 3. The playhead is less than or equal to the start time
    //    In this case, simply subtract the playhead from the start time
    else if(playheadTime <= scheduleItem.startTime) {
        region.mTimeStamp.mSampleTime -= schedule.playhead;
    }

    // 4. The playhead is in the middle of the file duration*loopCount
    //    In this case, set the start time to zero, adjust the loopCount
    //    startFrame and framesToPlay
    else {

        // First remove the start time
        region.mStartFrame = 0;
        double offsetTime = playheadTime - scheduleItem.startTime;

        // Next, take out any expired loops
        int loopsExpired = floor(offsetTime/file.duration);
        int fullLoops = region.mLoopCount - loopsExpired;
        region.mLoopCount = 0;
        offsetTime -= (loopsExpired * file.duration);

        // Then, adjust this segment of a loop accordingly
        region.mStartFrame = offsetTime * file.sampleRate;
        region.mFramesToPlay = region.mFramesToPlay - region.mStartFrame;

        // Finally, schedule any remaining loops separately
        if(fullLoops > 0) {
            ScheduledAudioFileRegion loops;
            [file setRegion:&loops schedule:scheduleItem];
            loops.mStartFrame = region.mFramesToPlay;
            loops.mLoopCount = fullLoops-1;
            if(![super.errors check:AudioUnitSetProperty(unit, kAudioUnitProperty_ScheduledFileRegion, kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0, &region, sizeof(region))
                           location:@"AudioUnitSetProperty(ScheduledFileRegion)"])
                return false;
        }
    }

    // Set the region
    if(![super.errors check:AudioUnitSetProperty(unit, kAudioUnitProperty_ScheduledFileRegion, kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0, &region, sizeof(region))
                   location:@"AudioUnitSetProperty(ScheduledFileRegion)"])
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Smack Jack,       did you ever run into a problem where your saved play-head position was sporadically 0.5-1 second earlier then you expected it to be? In other words you pressed pause, then when you un-paused, the track started a little earlier in the sound file/loop then it was when you pressed the pause button the first time?

Comment: @Beleg I haven't noticed that, but I suspect that if you don't stop the graph first, the time it takes to query one or more items could throw it off, as others have discussed here [list.apple.com](http://lists.apple.com/archives/coreaudio-api/2012/Jul/msg00139.html). However, a full second seems like an awful lot without something else going on.

Comment: Something else must be going on as I am stopping the AuGraph first. I asked this in another stack overflow question and just created a bounty, hopefully someone knows the answer.

Comment: I can't add comments to that Q (not enough rep), but I'd be happy to try and reproduce it if you have more complete sample code that shows the issue, see where it differs from my code.  Can you create a stripped down sample that demonstrates what you are seeing?

Comment: how would i send it to you?

Comment: @Beleg I would just expand the question that you have up with a more complete sample class so that others can try and reproduce what you have... that way everyone can see exactly what you are looking at.  As it is, there's a lot of the implementation that has to be assumed.